# Run Jasmine Spec multiple times in one execution

Tags: javascript, jasmine

I want to run my jasmine test cases multiple times in one execution. Is there any looping or any other method to execute particular specs in one execution.

Comment: You can use for/while loops just as in normal code. Can you give an example of what you try to do.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can run specs in an ordinary for loop like this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 1000; ++i) {
    it("random is in [0;1)", function () {
      var r = Math.random();
      expect(r >= 0 && r < 1).toBeTruthy();        
   });
}
```

If you want to run it with different parameters it's a little bit tricky. You have to bind the loop parameter to a closure scope, otherwise the test will be called with last value of the loop parameter all the time.

```
// WRONG: test called 10 times with i == 10
for(var i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    it("i ^ 0 is 1", function () {
      expect(Math.pow(i, 0)).toEqual(1);
   });
}

// CORRECT: called with 1, 2, 3, 4....
for(var i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
  (function(num) {
    it("i ^ 0 is 1", function () {
      expect(Math.pow(num, 0)).toEqual(1);
   });
  })(i);
}
```

Comment: There is a possible problem with this approach. Jasmine does not recreate test environment between tests, so any cleanup has to be manual and is usually put inside 'afterEach' function, which is expected to fire between tests, however, it will not in this case.

Answer (score 4):

I'm using Standalone Release of Jasmine 2.0 with customized SpecRunner.html on a web server.

AFAIK, there is no looping function on Jasmine 2.0.

If you want to run whole test multiple times in the iteration of development, you can customize SpecRunner to reload result page automatically.
I had written an auto refresh function that checks test spec and target's 'Last-Modified' header.

If you want to run multiple times a case, simply put *describe() or it()* into loop.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; ++i){
    describe('test multiple times', function () {
        it('may be fine', function () {
            expect(Math.random() < 0.5).toBeTruthy();
        });
    });
}
```

But the result would be ugly.

Answer (score 4):

You can `module.export` your specs, create a master spec and `require` your specs as many times as needed, and finally add the master spec in Jasmine.

Detailed Tutorial: [How to run identical Jasmine specs multiple times with Protractor](http://ramt.in/how-to-run-identical-jasmine-specs-multiple-times-with-protractor/)

Comment: The link is dead, is the content moved somewhere?